# generar id unico en python

Tags: python, python-3.7

[image: Me aparece asi a la hora de mostrar los datos todos con un id 1]Hola me pueden ayudar tengo el siguiente problema a la hora de usar esta fraccion de mi codigo no me genera el conrador para mi id es decir siempre me aparece 1 en cada cliente que guarde mi codigo es el siguiente

```
class Cliente(Persona):
    idCliente = 0
    def __init__(self, nombre, cedula, estado):
        super().__init__(nombre, estado)
        self.idCliente = Cliente.idCliente =+ 1
        self.cedula = cedula

    def mostarDatos(self):
        print("\nCliente: ", self.idCliente)
        print("Nombre:", Persona.nombre)
        print("Cedula:", Persona.cedula)
        print("Estado:", Persona.estado)
```

Comment: Ya intentaste poner: self.idCliente = Cliente.idCliente + 1 Saludos

Comment: El código contiene errores de sintaxis y no ejecuta. Por favor, revisalo bien. Puedes editar la pregunta con la versión correcta.

Comment: Hola si ya lo intente

Comment: Las consecuencias de eso sería que todos los self.idCliente serían 1, pues nunca actualizas Cliente.idCliente. Una buena respuesta contiene código ejecutable que demuestra su funcionamiento.

Comment: Y que explica como funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas con tu código:

- Relativo al id único que quieres crear, deberías incrementar la variable de clase, en lugar de la variable del objeto. Si no, la variable de clase siempre vale 0 y por tanto todos los objetos tendrán como id `0+1`, es decir, 1
- Relativo al método que muestra los datos, debes usar `self` para mostrar los atributos del objeto, y no los de la clase (de hecho, la clase no tiene esos atributos)

Con estas correcciones queda así:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, estado):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.estado = estado
        
class Cliente(Persona):
    idCliente = 0
    def __init__(self, nombre, cedula, estado):
        super().__init__(nombre, estado)
        Cliente.idCliente += 1
        self.idCliente = Cliente.idCliente
        self.cedula = cedula

    def mostarDatos(self):
        print("\nCliente: ", self.idCliente)
        print("Nombre:", self.nombre)
        print("Cedula:", self.cedula)
        print("Estado:", self.estado)
```

Una demo de uso:

```
# Creamos 5 clientes, todos con los mismos datos, pero deberían obtener
# diferente id
clients = [Cliente("Juan", "123456789", "Activo") for i in range(5)]

# Los mostramos
for c in clients:
    c.mostarDatos()
```

Resultado:

```
Cliente:  1
Nombre: Juan
Cedula: 123456789
Estado: Activo

Cliente:  2
Nombre: Juan
Cedula: 123456789
Estado: Activo

Cliente:  3
Nombre: Juan
Cedula: 123456789
Estado: Activo

Cliente:  4
Nombre: Juan
Cedula: 123456789
Estado: Activo

Cliente:  5
Nombre: Juan
Cedula: 123456789
Estado: Activo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio demasiado